# Java argument type error

Tags: java, generics

The IDE complains: "Wrong 2nd argument type: found boolean, required: ?"

```
public void onItemClick(View view, int positon) {
    HashMap<String, ?> movie = (HashMap<String, ?>) movieData.getItem(positon);

    if(view.getId() == R.id.checkBox) {
        boolean selection = (boolean) movie.get("selection") ? false : true;

        // Error here
        movie.put("selection", selection);
    }
}
```

However, this one will work

```
public void onItemClick(View view, int positon) {
    HashMap movie = movieData.getItem(positon);

    if(view.getId() == R.id.checkBox) {
        boolean selection = (boolean) movie.get("selection") ? false : true;

        movie.put("selection", selection);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) On what line is the IDE complaining?  (2) How is `movieData` declared?

Comment: Can you share the  IDE complaining and the method declaration?

Comment: Side note: if `b` is any Boolean expression, you don't have to say `b ? false : true`;  `!b` will work just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Java Tutorials page for [Unbounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html), it states:

> It's important to note that `List<Object>` and `List<?>` are not the same. You can insert an `Object`, or any subtype of `Object`, into a `List<Object>`. But you can only insert `null` into a `List<?>`. The [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) section has more information on how to determine what kind of wildcard, if any, should be used in a given situation.

You should consider the reasoning for using a wildcard here. If possible, don't use a wildcard. If you still need to use one, use an appropriate [Upper Bounded Wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) so that the type can be known.

Since you're storing a `Boolean` among other data types, the only common parent is `Object`:

```
HashMap<String, Object> movie;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help 4castle

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line to below:

`HashMap<String, Boolean> movie = (HashMap<String, Boolean>)`

In generics, If you use '?' wildcard, its a type called unknown type which means you cannot put Boolean for unknown type. Hope it will work for you.

Here is very good [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) for wildcards in generics, I will suggest you to read it once.

Comment: Because the map stores data with different types, so I can't just declare it as <String, Boolean>. However, if I use HashMap movie = movieData.getItem(positon);  it will work

Comment: Can you check with like this...
HashMap<String, Boolean> movie = (HashMap<String, ?>) movieData.getItem(positon);
I think you can declare like this because in you method you are putting Boolean as values and because you are not sure about the typr then in right hand side you can use wildcard type. This way your code will stick to Generics which is good.

Comment: @pbajpai21 That won't work, because it will still restrict the map to storing only booleans. The OP said they are storing other data types also.

Answer (score 0):

generic does not accept primitive type.It accept Only Object.so you should use like that  `Map<String,Boolean> mp = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();`

Comment: Because the map stores data with different types, so I can't just declare it as <String, Boolean>.

Comment: @Rangtian Yu ,You can use HashMap<String, Object> movie as 4castle said,or you can also do like that  Boolean selectedBoolean;boolean selection =  = (boolean) movie.get("selection") ? false : true; selectedBoolean = selection;movie.put("Selection",selectedBoolean);

Comment: Thank you for your help sawyinwaimon